# Include (another) file when executing .exe from Process.Start

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code that when executed with a button(example), will Start the program `rkill.exe`. However when `rkill.exe` starts (cmdline interface), it requires the file lpt$vpn.709. How can I include this file when calling `rkillProcess.Start()` ?

Code- This works, but need to include lpt$vpn.709 ?

```
   Dim rkillProcess As New Process

   rkillProcess.StartInfo.FileName = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Tools\McAffee\rkill\rkill.exe"

            rkillProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

            rkillProcess.Start()
```

Of course `rkill.exe` runs fine if I double click it from its directory with lpt$vpn.709 included in directory. However for my programs purpose I need `rkill.exe`to be launched with a button event. This is why I need to include lpt$vpn.709 in order for rkill to run.

Comment: I'm sure there are EULAs regarding the distribution of McAffee's software.

Comment: Did you set the processes working directory?

Comment: Dan-0 : This .exe is not produce by McAfee.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Mark!

This works:

```
syscleanProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Tools\TrendMicro\sysclean\"


 syscleanProcess.StartInfo.FileName = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Tools\TrendMicro\sysclean\sysclean"
```